# How to synchronize between scale and height in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a tower of stones from stones stacked one on top of the other. I have two problems:

1. I have not figured out how to randomize every stone as an instance, so now I can only randomize the scale of each one, but they all look similar.
2. There is a space between each stone when each stone is scaled separately, and I tried to eliminate this space by translating, but this did not work.
   [image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BKKP0MkU4rvlGEecSdYrXWCXrgEmHeLc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulties in this task lie in two points:

- First, you want the individual stones to look different.
- Second, you want them to be instantiated along a line with no distance between them.

You would therefore have to somehow know the height of a single stone.

This wouldn't be a problem if you didn't additionally derive all stones from a base shape (a *Cone*) and apply a subdivision. This changes the dimensions of a stone.

I would therefore solve this as follows:

[image]
[image]

- Here I create the base shape first and use `Subdivision Surface` right at the beginning. This way I get my base mesh in the desired resolution.
- Then I move this object, so that it sits again at the zero point (the subdivision has reduced the size of the object).
- Then I duplicate this object and scale the duplicates with randomly generated values.
- From these differently scaled objects I create bounding boxes. When these are scaled to zero on the *X* and *Y* axes, I can derive the height of a single object.
- I accumulate these heights at the end to move the individual instances to the resulting positions.
- In the last step I apply a `Noise Texture` to give the stones different shapes. Since the mesh was created completely before, the intersections between the stones also move uniformly and there are no unwanted distances.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial that achieves exactly what I wanted:
[New Blender 3.1 Geometry Node: Accumulate Field - Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiSi0HC7-aM&ab_channel=JohnnyMatthews)